# How to place two code snippets next to each other with minted?

Tags: vertical-alignment, multicol, minted

The [`minted` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/minted) for code highlighting comes with a float environment called `listing`. Now I would like to place two of this code listings next to each other, but I have no idea how to do this. I tried using the `multicol` package, but code of the two listings overlapped.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

EDIT:
Here is some little macro I created for convenience and an example on its usage.

```
\newcommand{\insertminted}[2]{\inputminted[linenos=true,
                                       frame=lines,
                                       framesep=2mm,
                                       xleftmargin=2cm,
                                       xrightmargin=2cm]{#1}{#2}}


\begin{listing}[H]
  \insertminted{xml}{code_examples/user.xml}
  \insertminted{js}{code_examples/user.js}
  \caption{SomeCaption}
  \label{lst:representation_examples}
\end{listing}
```

This way the code of `user.xml` is above the code of `user.js`. What I would like to have is the code next to each other in two cols, so that it can be compared. I also would like to have a seperate caption for each of them. The listing as a whole should appear in the output of `\listoflistings`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: Could you post what you have so far? It's always good to show what you've done so that folks don't have to create things from scratch :)

Comment: Thx for the fast responses! I added some more information to my original post. If need be I can put up a minimal example document on the morrow. This is not as easy, because this is deeply nested within my bachelor thesis. :)

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Have you considered using two `minipages`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `minted` package provides the `listing` environment, which is a `float`. My first attempt was to put `minipages` inside of the `listing` environment together with their own `captions`. This did not work, sadly.

Instead, I have used the `caption` package (with `compatibility=false` as detailed in the `minted` documentation) and then put two `minted` environments inside a `figure` environment (so that it floats), and used the `captionof` command to get the appropriate captions.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[compatibility=false]{caption}
\usepackage{minted}


\begin{document}
\listoflistings

\vspace{2cm}

\begin{figure}[!h]
 \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{minted}{python}
  some code
  \end{minted}
  \captionof{listing}{Sub caption}
 \end{minipage}
 \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{minted}{python}
  some other code
  \end{minted}
  \captionof{listing}{Another sub caption}
 \end{minipage}
 \captionof{listing}{SomeCaption}
  \label{lst:representation_examples}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

For anyone new to the `minted` package you'll need `python-pygments`

```
sudo apt-get install python-pygments
```

and you need to run `pdflatex` with

```
 pdflatex -shell-escape myfile.tex
```

both of which are detailed in the documentation.

Comment: Thx a lot, this works exactly as I want.

Comment: I already tried, need to get 15 reputation before I can upvote. I will do it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 8):

Using a `minipage` is an easy way to get two things next to each other. Here is an example using `lstlisting` from the `listings` package. You should be able to adapt this for the `minted` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Some XML Caption}]
  .. xml code ...
  .. xml code ...
  .. xml code ...
  .. xml code ...
  .. xml code ...
  .. xml code ...
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Some Javascript Caption}]
  ... javascript code ...
  ... javascript code ...
  ... javascript code ...
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what documentclass `standalone` is, but it gives me a compile error. If I change this to `article` it works.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: You must have an old distribution as [the `standalone` package/class](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/standalone) has been part of the standard distribution for a while now.

Comment: Not that old.TeX Live 2009 as packaged for Debian squeeze.

Comment: this is weired the alignment of the numbers in the minipage does not align with the numbers of a listing that I have outside of the minipage.

Comment: @Arne: Without more info it is difficult to help you. I suggest you ask a new question and include a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem.  If this question is releavant you can reference it in the question.