# Aligning minipages in lstlisting

Tags: listings, minipage, code, alignment, baseline

I'm trying to use two `minipage`s inside an `lstnewenvironment` and I'm struggling with top- aligning the two minipages.

```
\lstnewenvironment{code}
{   
    \lstset{
        language=Python, 
        mathescape=true, 
        backgroundcolor=\color{cellbackground}, 
        numbers=right,
        numbersep=5pt,
        resetmargins=true,
        rulecolor=\color{cellbackground}
    }
    \addtocounter{inputcounter}{1}
    \minipage[t]{0pt}
    \footnotesize\ttfamily\llap{{\color{incolor}In [\theinputcounter]:\hspace{3pt}\boxspacing}}
    \endminipage%
    \minipage[t]{\pagewidth}
}{
    \endminipage
}
```

But when I use the new environment, the output looks like this:

[image]

Is there any way to make the `In [1]:` and the `2 + 2` lines aligned (on the same baseline)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is a similar question asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187558/aligning-two-minipages-one-with-lstlisting-one-without-on-top?rq=1).

The answer is setting:

```
aboveskip=-1.4\medskipamount
```

on the `lstnewenvironment`, which moves the actual listing environment up, relative to the first minipage.

The entire `lstnewenvironment` becomes:

```
\lstnewenvironment{pfainput}
{   
    \lstset{
        language=Python, 
        aboveskip=-1.4\medskipamount,
        mathescape=true, 
        backgroundcolor=\color{cellbackground}, 
        numbers=right,
        numbersep=5pt,
        resetmargins=true,
        rulecolor=\color{cellbackground}
    }
    \addtocounter{inputcounter}{1}
    \minipage[t]{0pt}
    \footnotesize\ttfamily\llap{{\color{incolor}In [\theinputcounter]:\hspace{3pt}\boxspacing}}
    \endminipage
    \minipage[t]{\pagewidth}
}{
    \endminipage
}
```

I'll wait for other answers, but for now, this seems to do the trick.