# Placing two code snippets next to each other with minted with a headline over each snippet causes box shift

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage, minted

I am refering to this question:
[How to place two code snippets next to each other with minted?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36712/how-to-place-two-code-snippets-next-to-each-other-with-minted?newreg=bfb9dc023dd440ea880970265f08a73b)

I am trying to use the answer provided there, but with a headline over each code snippet.
Sadly, this is causing a vertical shift of the right box, so that the right box is placed a bit below the left box.

The first figure in the code is with headlines (VBS and JS), the other is without headlines.

```
\documentclass[
ngerman, % German
english, % English (default)
toc=listof,
toc=bibliography,
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{minted}
% \usepackage{mathpazo} --> This is causing the shift of the boxes!

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        VBS
        \begin{minted}[fontsize=\footnotesize, frame=single]{vbscript}
            EXAMPLE CODE
            EXAMPLE CODE
            EXAMPLE CODE
        \end{minted}
        %\captionof{figure}{VBS}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        JS
        \begin{minted}[fontsize=\footnotesize, frame=single]{js}
            EXAMPLE CODE
            EXAMPLE CODE
            EXAMPLE CODE
        \end{minted}
        %\captionof{figure}{JS}
    \end{minipage}
    \captionof{figure}{TEST 1.}
    \label{figure:test1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{minted}[fontsize=\footnotesize, frame=single]{vbscript}
            EXAMPLE CODE
            EXAMPLE CODE
            EXAMPLE CODE
        \end{minted}
        %\captionof{figure}{VBS}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{minted}[fontsize=\footnotesize, frame=single]{js}
            EXAMPLE CODE
            EXAMPLE CODE
            EXAMPLE CODE
        \end{minted}
        %\captionof{figure}{JS}
    \end{minipage}
    \captionof{figure}{TEST 2.}
    \label{figure:test2}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Please extend your code to be compilable, beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.  Different document classes could have different results, so we need more information to produce an accurate answer.

Comment: @Martin Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines-why-is-my-macro-creat . The missing % signs after your minipages will act like spaces and thus make your line wider than 2 times .5\linewidth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem.
**The package mathpazo caused the shift of the minipage-boxes.**

No idea why, I will just leave the package out - but if someone wants to investigate this, please answer in this thread.